# Не срабатывает дуструкторизация массива при объявление

Tags: javascript, html

Массив array не записывается в items, она равна пустому массива.

```
let array=['html', 'css', 'js']

    let { items = [] }= array
    
    console.log(items );
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю чего вы хотите добиться, если просто перезаписать массив, сделайте let items = array . Дуструкторизация массива делается так: let [html, css, js] = array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может вам это нужно?

```js
let array = ['html', 'css', 'js']
let [ h,c,j ] = array

console.log(h)
console.log(c)
console.log(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

Оставлю этот ответ, если нужна была не деструктуризация, а копирование элементов массива:

```js
const array = ['html', 'css', 'js']

const items = [...array];

console.log(items);
```